# seaborn violin plot with frequency and values in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have some DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(1)
data = {'values': range(0,200,1), 'frequency': np.random.randint(low=0, high=2000, size=200)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to create a violin plot where the y-axis corresponds to the `values` column and the width of the violin corresponds to the `frequency` column.

I can duplicate each row by the value in the `frequency` column and then call a violin plot:

```
repeat_df = df.loc[df['values'].repeat(df['frequency'])]
sns.violinplot(y=repeat_df['values'])
```

[image]

This works...except when the resulting duplicated DataFrame has 50+ million rows. What is a better solution when working with large DataFrames?

Comment: 50+ million observation sounds like far to much detail for the  KDE of the violin plot. Is normalization of the frequencies or binning of the values and option for you to reduce the data density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment:

Before repeating the frequencies, reduce their resolution to a percent level, by normalizing and rounding them to an integer range of 0 to 100.

This way, you are not loosing significant amount of detail but keep the amount of repetitions to a maximum of 100.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
n_values = 50000
# creating values with sinusoidal frequency modulation
data = {'values': range(0,n_values,1), 'frequency': np.random.randint(low=0, high=2000, size=n_values)*(np.sin(np.arange(n_values)/(n_values/50))+2)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# old method: 100 million rows after repeat
repeat_df = df.loc[df['values'].repeat(df['frequency'])]
print(f"Old method: {len(repeat_df)} Observations")

# new method: renormalize and round frequency to reduce repetitions to 100
# resulting in <2 million rows after repeat 
df.frequency = np.round(df.frequency / df.frequency.max() * 100)
repeat_df = df.loc[df['values'].repeat(df['frequency'])]
print(f"New method: {len(repeat_df)} normalized Observations")

sns.violinplot(y=repeat_df['values'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

If your 50+ million rows stem from the values instead, I would rebin those values accordingly, e.g. to a set of 100 values.